# F# syntax error

Tags: f#, syntax-error, function-calls

I'm having a syntax error.
I want to take the floor of a function that returns a floating point number.

I *thought* this would give me the right answer

```
let cyclesPerInterrupt bps bpw cpu factor = 
 floor (fudge (float(factor) cyclesPerWord cpu wordsPerSec bps bpw))
```

But it doesn't. I've tried everything I can think of, and it's just not coming together for me. I know it's something stupid, but I can't think of it.

For reference, fudge takes a float and an integer, cyclesPerWord takes 2 integers and wordsPerSec takes 2 integers. Floor takes a generic and returns a float.

Answer (score 3):

Note also that you can use parens to nest the function calls the way you were originally trying to, e.g.

```
...(cyclesPerWord cpu (wordsPerSec bps bpw))
```

(Without the inner set of parens above, it's kinda like you're trying to pass 4 arguments to cyclesPerWord, which is not what you want.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, to avoid let blindness and parenthesis paralysis, use some pipelining |> :

```
let fudge (a : float) (b : int) =
    a

let cyclesPerWord (a : int) (b : int) =
    a

let wordsPerSec (a : int) (b : int) =
    a

let cyclesPerInterrupt bps bpw cpu factor =
    wordsPerSec bps bpw
    |> cyclesPerWord cpu
    |> fudge factor
    |> floor
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your function definition, it seems like you are using a C# like syntax for calling your functions, the function name exists right before the ( ) and the associated parameters for that function are within the ( ).  An example would be FunctionName(Parameter1 Parameter2).  F# doesn't use that style.  Instead it uses a style where the function name and associated parameters exist inside the ( ).  An example of this would be (FunctionName Parameter1 Parameter2).

The correct way to express your code would be

```
  let cyclesPerInterrupt bps bpw cpu factor = 
    (floor (fudge (float factor) (cyclesPerWord cpu (wordsPerSec bps bpw) ) ) )
```

though the outermost ( ) are not really necessary.

Comment: Aaah. I've been trying to figure that out.